# Implementing generated interface with JavaPoet

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

I would like to use [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) to generate an interface and a class implementing this interface.

```
TypeSpec if = TypeSpec.interfaceBuilder("MyInterface")
                      .build();

TypeSpec cl = TypeSpec.classBuilder("MyClass")
                      .build();
```

But I am strugelling to tell JavaPoet that `MyClass` should implement `MyInterface`. The method `addSuperinterface(TypeName)` requires a type name and I didn't findout how to turn a `TypeSpec` into an `TypeName`. The only way I found is calling `ClassName#get(String, String)`.

Is there an better way to achive this and to use the type specification for the interface directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as complicated as it may seem.
The TypeSpec.Builder has two versions of the addSuperInterface method:

```
TypeSpec.Builder    addSuperinterface(Type superinterface) 
TypeSpec.Builder    addSuperinterface(TypeName superinterface)
```

We could use the second version for example and obtain the super interface as an instance of the TypeName class using `ClassName.get`

One of the signatures of the get method of the ClassName class is:

```
public static ClassName get(String packageName, String simpleName, String... simpleNames)
```

So we could use it with empty string for the package name since you did not specify any package name in your interface spec. It will work because ClassName **extends** TypeName.
On the other hand we can obtain the interface's simple name using the type spec's name property.

Here a complete sample implementation. I modified the name of the variables (the variable name **if** that you used for the interface spec will not work as it is a java keyword).

```
@Data
public class SimpleClassSpecs {

    public final TypeSpec interfaceSpec;
    public final TypeSpec classSpec;

    public SimpleClassSpecs() {
        interfaceSpec = TypeSpec.interfaceBuilder("MyInterface")
                .build();

        TypeName interfaceTypeName = ClassName.get("", interfaceSpec.name);
        classSpec = TypeSpec.classBuilder("MyClass")
                .addSuperinterface(interfaceTypeName)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I used Lombok's **@Data** for the boilerplate code (getters and setters...) 
Here is a corresponding test (assertion written with assertj):

```
@Test
public void should_generate_spec_with_superInterface() {
   SimpleClassSpecs ps = new SimpleClassSpecs();
   assertThat(ps.classSpec.toString()).contains("class MyClass implements MyInterface");
}
```

Or by simply doing doing a `System.out.println(ps.classSpec)`, one can obtain the following result:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
}
```